# Getting sum from price and quantity of an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am trying to get the sum of prices * quantity for each item in an array.

I have this array:

```
var itemsInCart = [Order(productUID: "abc1", productName: "Shoe", productPrice: 100, quantity: 1), Order(productUID: "abc2", productName: "Shirt", productPrice: 150, quantity: 1), Order(productUID: "abc3", productName: "Pants", productPrice: 180, quantity: 1)]
```

So the thing I cannot figure out is how to combine the price and the quantity of each item in the array, to get and update my variable `var totalCost = ""`

I know I can use this piece of code, to get the sum of prices, but how to get the quantity too?

```
let sum = itemsInCart.reduce(0, +)
```

Any help or points in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: I would add a computed property to Order that returns the amount, `var amount: Int { productPrice * quantity }`. Then you could use `reduce`together with `map`, `let some = itemsInCart.map(\.amount).reduce(0, +)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
let sum = itemsInCart.map { $0.productPrice * $0.quantity }.reduce(0, +)
```

Or:

```
let sum = itemsInCart.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.productPrice * $1.quantity }
```

Comment: You might like to avoid the "map and then reduce", if you write it as itemsInCart.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.productPrice * $1.quantity }

Comment: @Shadowrun yes it's another option too